# python built-in function type()

Tags: python

so I was writing a function consume a list to count how many different types of data in it and return a list of natural numbers by an order of integer, float, string, Boolean, other

```
[integer, float, string, Boolean, others]
```

for example
let

```
L = [1, "123", !, #, 2.0, True, False, [1,2]]
```

then funcition(L) will return

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

I choose the built-in function type() to determine the data type
for example

```
type(L[0]) == type(9)
```

then I know if first element of the list is an integer.
but when the list contains some symbols like "!@#$%^", then the type() function 
doesn't work anymore, it will display

```
Syntax Error: invalid syntax: <string>
```

So I wonder if there is another way to classify symbols and put them into the "other" type.

Comment: But `!` and `#` are **not valid objects to begin with**...

Comment: Not an answer to your problem, but if you want to count types, why not just do `collections.Counter(map(type, L))`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is **not** the `type(..)` function that does not work: **the error occurs when constructing the list**.

When a compiler/interpreter reads code, it will aim to *generate an abstract syntax tree* according to the *grammar* of the language. `!` and `#` are simply *invalid grammar*. The `#` is interpreted as the start of a comment, so the interpreter will read:

```
L = [1, "123", !,
```

But that does not make any sense either since `!` is not valid, and even if you would remove the `!`, then Python will still complain it cannot find a matching `]` (to close the list).

Now let's assume you sort that out, there is another problem: what with *subclassing*? One can for instance subclass a `str`ing. Do you count it as a `str` or other? The problem is more troublesome because Python supports multiple inheritance: something can be a `str`ing and a `bool` at the **same time**. Let us assume we only count real `str`ings and not subclasses, then we can write the following code:

```
def count_types(data):
    the_types = [int,float,str,bool]
    result = [0]*(len(the_types)+1)
    for x in data:
        tyx = type(x)
        for idx,ty in enumerate(the_types):
            if tyx is ty:
                result[idx] += 1
                break
        else:
            result[-1] += 1
    return result
```

This would produce:

```
>>> count_types([1, "123", 2.0, True, False, [1,2]])
[1, 1, 1, 2, 1]
```

Nevertheless it is weird that you want to return a list *without context*, and furthermore that you only count specific types. I guess a more elegant and faster solution, is to generate a `Counter` with types:

```
from collections import Counter

result = Counter(type(x) for x in data)
```

This generates:

```
>>> Counter(type(x) for x in data)
Counter({<class 'bool'>: 2, <class 'list'>: 1, <class 'str'>: 1, <class 'float'>: 1, <class 'int'>: 1})
```

Comment: Pedantic note on "something can be a string and a `bool` at the **same time**": You picked a bad example; `bool` is not subclassable (at the C level, you have to opt in to subclassability, and `bool`, `slice`, `NoneType` and a handful of other core classes, usually once you don't create directly, often ones with a restricted set of singleton values, don't set that flag). And while `str` is subclassable, the subclasses can't use multiple inheritance with most (all?) other built-in types or `__slots__`ed types (you get an instance lay-out conflict; they expand `PyObject` in incompatible ways).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compare types (even though it's not a Pythonic way) you need to use isinstance()

```
 isinstance(L[0], type(9))
```

or

```
 isinstance(L[0], str)
```

Comment: This will classify `True` as `int`. I think in OP's scenario, comparing to types directly is the better option. And in any way, it is not related to OP's problem.

Comment: Then OP has to compare to with direct but with abstract classes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to count your types, then use `operator.itemgetter()` in order to get the desire result based on your expected order:

```
In [32]: order = [int, float, str, bool, 'other']

In [33]: l = [1, 3, 5.6, 'st', True, 'gg', False, None, lambda x: 3, sum]

In [34]: from collections import defaultdict

In [35]: from operator import itemgetter

In [36]: d = defaultdict(int)                    

In [37]: for i in l:                             
             t = type(i)
             if t in order:
               d[t] += 1
             else:
               d['other'] += 1
   ....:             

In [38]: itemgetter(*order)(d)                    
Out[38]: (2, 1, 2, 2, 3)
```